# c#: tryparse vs convert

Tags: c#, parsing

Today I read an article where it's written that we should always use `TryParse(string, out MMM)` for conversion rather than `Convert.ToMMM()`.

I agree with article but after that I got stuck in one scenario.

When there will always be some valid value for the string and hence we can also use `Convert.ToMMM()` because we don't get any exception from `Convert.ToMMM()`.

What I would like to know here is: Is there any performance impact when we use `TryParse` because when I know that the out parameter is always going to be valid then we can use `Convert.ToMMM()` rather `TryParse(string, out MMM)`.

What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

If you **know** the value can be converted, just use `Parse()`. If you 'know' that it can be converted, and it can't, then an exception being thrown is a good thing.

**EDIT:** Note, this is in comparison to using `TryParse` or `Convert` without error checking. If you use either of the other methods *with* proper error checking then the point is moot. I'm just worried about your assumption that you *know* the value can be converted. If you want to skip the error checking, use Parse and die immediately on failure rather than possibly continuing and corrupting data.

Answer (score 1):

When the input to `TryParse`/`Convert.ToXXX` comes from user input, I'd always use `TryParse`. In case of database values, I'd check why you get `string`s from the database (maybe bad design?). If string values *can* be entered in the database columns, I'd also use `TryParse` as you can never be sure that nobody modifies data manually.

**EDIT**
Reading Matthew's reply: If you are unsure and would wrap the conversion in a try-catch-block anyway, you might consider using `TryParse` as it is said to be way faster than doing a try-catch in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There is significant difference regarding the developing approach you use.

***Convert***: Converting one "primitive" data in to another type and corresponding format using multiple options
Case and point - converting an integer number in to its bit by bit **representation**. Or hexadecimal number (as string) in to integer, etc... 
**Error Messages** : Conversion Specific Error Message - for problems in multiple cases and at multiple stages of the conversion process.

***TryParse:*** Error-less transfer from one data format to another. Enabling T/F control of possible or not.
**Error Messages:** NONE 
**NB:** Even after passing the data in to a variable - the data passed is the **default** of the type we try to parse in to.

***Parse***: in essence taking some data in one format and transfer it in to another. No representations and nothing fancy.
**Error Messages:** Format-oriented

P.S. Correct me if I missed something or did not explain it well enough.